# Node.js MongoDB Upsert update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert

I'm writing a little application which scores keywords. So if "beirut" and "education" get entered in, if they haven't been seen before, I want to create a mongo entry, and give them a score of 1. If they have, I want to increment their score by one. I'm trying to do this with one update command, but I think I might be doing it wrong.

- Ranking is the object representing the database
- "key" is the keyword

```js
rankingdb.update(
    {keyword:key},
    {keyword:key, {$inc:{score:1}}},
    {upsert:true, safe:false},
    function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
      else {
          console.log("score succeeded");
      }
    }
);
```

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Can you not create a brand new document with an increment?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your general approach is right, but as the error message suggests, you've got a syntax problem in your code.

Try this instead:

```
rankingdb.update(
    {keyword: key},
    {$inc: {score: 1}},
    {upsert: true, safe: false},
    function(err,data){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("score succeded");
        }
    }
);
```

When an upsert needs to create a new object it combines the fields from the selector (first parameter) and the update object (second parameter) when creating the object so you don't need to include the `keyword` field in both.

Note that [`update()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#update) is deprecated in the 2.0 driver, so you should now use either `updateOne()` or `updateMany()`.